# How do I take a set of arrays (strings) and create a multidimensional slice of those arrays in Golang?

Tags: arrays, go, multidimensional-array, slice, arrayofarrays

I am trying to implement a function, that when passed an array of strings, it creates a slice of arrays, and adds to it every array that is passed. It would return the final slice of all arrays that was passed.

Just as a test, I initialized 4 arrays and tried to create a function that would do just this. However, it fails quite miserably. This is what I have so far. Not sure how to go about this.

```
func main() {
    array1 := []string{"x", "o", "x", "_", "_"}
    array2 := []string{"0", "o", "x", "_", "_"}
    array3 := []string{"o", "o", "o", "_", "_"}
    array4 := []string{"o", "o", "o", "o", "o"}

    FinalSlice(array1)
    FinalSlice(array2)
    FinalSlice(array3)
    fmt.Println(FinalSlice(array4))

}

func FinalSlice(array []string) [][]string {
    var slice [][]string
    for i, _ := range slice {
        slice[i] = array
    }
    return slice

}
```

Right now this is the output:

```
[]
```

Comment: Fixed: https://go.dev/play/p/Oz9sk0kcjgm

Comment: In your code: `for i, _ := range slice{` loops over an empty `slice` that you've declared in the preceding line. Looping over an empty slice gets you exactly **0** iterations, i.e. it's the same as no loop. Also `var slice [][]string` declares the slice within the surrounding scope, i.e. inside the `FinalSlice` function, and whenever you call `FinalSlice` you are allocating a new slice, the slices allocated by previous calls are not present anymore.

Comment: got it, that makes much more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you loop through an empty slice, which has no elements.

So your loop

```golang
for i, _ := range slice {}
```

will actually run 0 iteration (that's why you end up with an empty array).

I don't understand the exact result you want to achieve, but if you want to concat arrays into a multi-dimensional one, you can use the below code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func AppendSlice(source [][]string, value []string) [][]string {
    return append(source, value)
}

func main() {
    array1 := []string{"x", "o", "x", "_", "_"}
    array2 := []string{"0", "o", "x", "_", "_"}
    array3 := []string{"o", "o", "o", "_", "_"}
    array4 := []string{"o", "o", "o", "o", "o"}

    var finalArray [][]string

    finalArray = AppendSlice(finalArray, array1)
    finalArray = AppendSlice(finalArray, array2)
    finalArray = AppendSlice(finalArray, array3)
    finalArray = AppendSlice(finalArray, array4)

    // [[x o x _ _] [0 o x _ _] [o o o _ _] [o o o o o]]
    fmt.Println(finalArray) 
}
```

This may be improved in many ways, feel free to play around with this solution: https://go.dev/play/p/vXvqlRZuOUI

Comment: Yes this is precisely it. Concatenation of many array into one multi-dimensional slice. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how I can reformat the array so it looks like a matrix rather than one line of X arrays side by side?

Comment: @tosh-21 Display line by line ? You can loop through your array and print each row on a different line `for _, element := range finalArray { fmt.Println(element) }`

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't one just say something like

```
func bundleSlices( slices ...[]int) [][]int {
    return slices
}
```

And then:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    arr1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    arr2 := []int{4, 5, 6}
    arr3 := []int{7, 8, 9}

    bundled := bundleSlices( arr1, arr2, arr3 )

    fmt.Println(bundled)

}
```

to get

```
[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]]
```